# Can I use my spouses bank statement for UK tourist visa? My spouse is included on the application and will be traveling with me

Tags: usa, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

We use one account that belongs to my spouse to carry out most transactions. Like rent and groceries and direct deposit. I am applying for a UK tourist visa from the US and would like to know if I can use my spouses bank statement.

Comment: Do you have a bank account / income of your own? Are you financially dependent on your spouse? Does ‘included on the application’ mean your spouse is also applying for a visa?

Comment: You most likely can. However make sure you read the linked duplicate question to avoid making mistakes in your application.